# Unable to integrate with anonymous payment using "PayPal Payments Standard"

Tags: paypal

I am using "PayPal Payments Standard" to integrate PayPal with my application. I need the users to be able to pay using just their card information without having to create a PayPal account / log in to PayPal.

I understand that "Express Checkout" has this feature but I don't want to put the PayPal button on my application.

1. Is this feature available from the "Standard" API?
2. What settings will I need in order for this to work?

I am using a Business account for testing but I always am prompted to login / create new account when I redirect from my application.

Screenshot of what I am redirected to: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKnok.jpg

Answer (score 1):

"PayPal Payments Standard" has that feature available. Please check your account settings here:
Profile > My selling tools (or: My selling preferences) > Website Preferences > Update > PayPal Account Optional: On.

For "Express Checkout" you will have to set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your SetExpressCheckout API call. However, this not fully guarantee that guest payment will be allowed, it depends also the country of the seller.