# paypal express checkout in php

Tags: php, paypal

I am using paypal express checkout in php.

Click on the PayPal Checkout Button in the Checkout Page, it redirects to this url:

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&useraction=continue&token=EC-36W63504T07750042

However, most of the time it redirects to this URL (which requires a PayPal account):

> https://www.paypal.com/nl/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=We43k8ut0KrIZGW2R4iQgPZ9ambAP8i3ZFJL1-2SC9oykux_xIeDOyyzy0K&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198ecd47ed44bac94cd6fd721232afa4155

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check below documentation for Paypal express checkout

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/express-checkout/

You can also see the demo here and can download the code from below URL

https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/home

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer for same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388366/unable-to-integrate-with-anonymous-payment-using-paypal-payments-standard/30389588#30389588):

"PayPal Payments Standard" has that feature available. Please check your account settings here: Profile > My selling tools (or: My selling preferences) > Website Preferences > Update > PayPal Account Optional: On.

For "Express Checkout" you will have to set SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your SetExpressCheckout API call. However, this not fully guarantee that guest payment will be allowed, it depends also the country of the seller.

Answer (score 0):

The transformed URL is somehow related to your browser's SESSION, and it is not relevant to the guest checkout. Guest checkout is not always offered for all buyers. Network environment safety and some other factors will be considered for the final decision.